# Social preview not showing in social

Tags: dns, cloudflare, netlify, preview

I have recently added my site to cloudflare then i connected netlfiys's hosting which i uploadded my site by cloudlare the problem is when i share my site link hisobkitob.uz social preview not showing in social media, then when i share the link netlify gave me https://soemsmo1.netlify.app/ social media preview showing image, text, title, links

I was expecting social preview woking well without problems. I mean it should be working in social preview with image, title, desc, link.